# How to Convert image to NSData And that NSData To NSString

Tags: iphone

Here is the code i am Trying

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image)];
    imageClass.imageString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"String is :%@",imageClass.imageString); // getting NULL
```

getting String is :null

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804359/saving-images-in-string-format-to-use-in-xml-not-working ..there is a implementation for base64 encoding and decoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageData can't directly transfer to NSString,I have a suggestion,you can make this NSData to Base64 NSString,and if you wan't to covert back,then use Base64 from NSString to NSData,find A "GTMBase64.h",that will help you

Encode

```
NSString *imageStr = [GTMBase64 stringByEncodingData:imageData];
```

Decode

```
NSData *imageData = [GTMBase64 decodeString:imageStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert like that. First you should base64 encode it. For base64 encoding see the link https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR IMAGE Name" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

this may help you