# How do i attach image form ui view to email body

Tags: string, image, ios5, uiview, xcode4

I have a small ui view that alows user to select a pic form camera roll, i want to attach it along with my text fields in email.

```
.h
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

 .m
  NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@(textboxes and other outlets are      here)"%@"imageView.image];
```

When emailed  I get the text strings attached but not the image? Coul dsomeone point me in the right direction on this, thanks

xcode 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this link to send images by email

http://iosdevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html

if that is not what u want u may have to  convert image to nsdata using the functions

```
NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

now convert this data to string by base64encoding and then attach to string.

Comment: Thanks for reply, email body needs to be html, attaching the image along with the html text in the body is causing a problem, base64 encoding bit past my skills level i think.  Thanks anyway

Comment: in that case use these two category methods in ur code ...one for encoding and other for decoding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804359/saving-images-in-string-format-to-use-in-xml-not-working